# Is there or will there be ROS on Raspberry pi3 OS:Jessie

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

27.1.2017

I am about to start collecting information of my private autonomus robot system.
I would like to use the popular Raspberry Pi 3....

Question is:
Is there or will there be ROS on Raspberry pi3 OS:Jessie (Debian)
or must I use a different MB and, if so, which Board would you suggest ?

Many thanks for any assistance.

ROS could be ideal for my project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253153/is-there-or-will-there-be-ros-on-raspberry-pi3-os:jessie/) by [Bonzadog](https://answers.ros.org/users/29182/bonzadog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-27**:
You can definitely build ROS Indigo *from source* on Debian Jessie. But it's not as convenient as getting it from Debian packages.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-27**:
However, there's a *hacky workaround* for installing ROS Indigo on Jessie via `apt-get`. So if this is more of a hobby project, try this: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM You basically pretend that the RPi3 is running Ubuntu Trusty for ARM even though it's running Raspbian Jessie.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-01-27**:
It looks like you have three sides to the triangle - hardware, operating system, and level of effort. If you prioritize using the Raspberry Pi above using Raspbian Jessie, then you could go with Ubuntu 16.04 and Kinetic. Or Debian Jessie and different hardware. Or ROS source and more effort.

**Comment by [griz11@twc.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/26973/griz11@twc.com/) on 2017-02-12**:
No big deal to build from source on Jessie. Did it the other night. Posted a script in the pixhawk 2 group on fb. Anyone running ubuntu-mate with ROS?

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2017-02-12**:
I'm using Ubuntu Xenial (no GUI) with ROS Kinetic with good success. There are some caveats. The steps I've used are here: http://stemroller.com/page.php?page=sdcard-xenial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a reason you are using Raspbian? Ubuntu supports the Raspberry Pi 2 and 3 with Ubuntu Mate https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/

With Ubuntu Mat you can just install ROS regularly.

---

Originally posted by [inkspell4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28072/inkspell4/) with karma: 32 on 2017-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bonzadog](https://answers.ros.org/users/29182/bonzadog/) on 2017-02-12**:
I wanted to keep the same OS with all my projects. >This is the preferred OS by the RPI.org